# Maven dependency download error

Tags: maven

I have a build server that mirror all maven dependency lookup to a local sonatype nexus. Recently Maven isn't looking up the dependencies and i don't understand why.

In the .m2/settings.xml, of the build server, i have the following mirror setting.

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>http://my-host/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Building the project with the -X switch i get the following output

```
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       my.group:my.artifact:1.4.2-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, runtime, test]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [nexus (http://my-host/nexus/content/groups/public, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [nexus (http://my-host/nexus/content/groups/public, releases)]


[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata my.group:my.artifact-2:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/usr/local/jenkins/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata my.group:my.artifact-2:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/usr/local/jenkins/.m2/repository)
[WARNING] The POM for my.group:my.artifact-2:jar:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[DEBUG] my.group:my.artifact:jar:1.4.2-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]    my.group:yyyyy:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[DEBUG]       my.group:xxxx:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[DEBUG]          com.oracle:oracle-driver:jar:11.1:compile
[DEBUG]    my.group:my.artifact-2:jar:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[DEBUG]    my.group:zzzzz:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[DEBUG]       javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[DEBUG]    org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[DEBUG]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Browsing the Nexus interface i can see the my.group:my.artifact-2:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT artifact in there. In the build server, the folder /repository/my.group/my.artifact don't exists.

Comment: Check `<repositories>` section in pom.xml. I think your repository is defined only for releases, not snapshots.

Comment: Adding the `<repositories>` solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the `<repositories>` tag to the pom

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Repositório Central</name>
      <url>http://my-host/nexus/content/repositories</url>
      <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying any `pom.xml`, you could add the following in the build server's `.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<profile><id>alwaysactive</id>
    <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository><id>unused</id><url>unused</url></repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

This tells maven:

- you have a repository ("unused"), dont care where
- this repository contains snapshots (by default a repository contains both releases and snapshots)
- the mirror you already defined also mirrors this repo so maven search the mirror **also** for snapshots